# A problem related to Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity is

\begin{aligned}\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)\left(c^{2}+d^{2}\right)&{}=\left(ac-bd\right)^{2}+\left(ad+bc\right)^{2}&&(1)\\&{}=\left(ac+bd\right)^{2}+\left(ad-bc\right)^{2}.&&(2)\end{aligned}

I was wondering whether we can express the terms in LHS if the terms of RHS are given.

More precisely, If I write $ac+bd=A$  and $ad-bc = B,$ then is it possible to express $a^2+b^2$ and $c^2+d^2$ in the terms of $A$ and $B ?$

**The motivation behind the problem:** I wanted to prove the statement *If $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ then $p$ cannot be irreducible in $\mathbb{Z[i]}.$*

Comment: If you already showed that $p$ for $p\equiv 1 (\operatorname{mod}4)$ is a sum of squares: $p=a^2+b^2$, then $p=(a+ib)(a-ib)$ is reducible

Answer (score 3):

You have the values of $A$ and $B$, and:
$$ac+bd=A$$
$$ad-bc=B$$
Simply fix $a$ and $b$ to be whatever you want. Solve the above system of linear equations in two variables ($c$ and $d$). Thus, it is very clear that you can make $a^2+b^2$ to be any positive real number.

Comment: Sounds good to me! What if we allow $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ only? Does this argument still hold? Because that is what I need in the problem.